# How to connect a ps/2 keyboard to an arduino?

Tags: keyboard

I want to connect an old hp ps/2 keyboard to my arduino (nucleo 64 F303RE). The keyboard has a power rating of 5v and 50mA, I guess this is milliamps.
The ps/2 connector has 4 connecting cables:
GND
VCC
CLK
DATA
I have wired up the GND to the ground of the arduino and the VCC. However, the keyboard does not properly light up or respond to the caps key being pressed. I am able to measure suppodly 5v coming out of the clock pin.
What could be the issue?

I would have expected that the keyboard would display some leds and when the caps lock would be pressed at least the caps light would turn on or off.

Comment: You'll need (very old) documentation about the PS/2 protocol. If I remember correctly, the protocol requires pulling down the clock to start the communication. And send some "A"s to initialize the device.

Comment: https://www.eecg.utoronto.ca/~jayar/ece241_08F/AudioVideoCores/ps2/ps2.html#:~:text=for%20sending%20commands-,PS%2F2%20Keyboard%20protocol,the%20host%20and%20the%20keyboard.

Comment: there is a library https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard/ . use 5V to power the keyboard and use 5 V tolerant pins on the STM32